# C# threading crashing on 2nd thread, unsure how to do fix

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, for-loop

Just for fun I created a mandelbrot program. I'm now trying to make it multithreaded by splitting the image into two left/right parts to be handled by two threads. However, the application crashes as soon as it's launched (although based on my console output, the first thread continues after the crash but the second thread never starts) and I'm unsure what to do.

The crash is at the line `this.output[x][y] = this.calculate_pixel_rgb(x, y);` and says I'm missing an object reference, which I don't understand because it works for the first thread.

```
    public void compute_all()
    {
        this.setcolors(); this.zoom_multiplier = (4 / this.zoom / this.resolution);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(computation_thread)); thread1.Start(new double[] { 0, 0.5 });
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(computation_thread)); thread2.Start(new double[] { 0.5, 1 });
        thread1.Join(); thread2.Join();
    }

    public void computation_thread(object threadinfo)
    {
        double[] parameters = (double[])threadinfo;

        this.output = new int[this.resolution][][];
        for (int x = (int)(this.resolution * parameters[0]); x < (int)(this.resolution * parameters[1]); x++)
        {
            this.output[x] = new int[this.resolution][];
            for (int y = 0; y < this.resolution; y++)
            {
                this.output[x][y] = this.calculate_pixel_rgb(x, y);
                this.pixels_completed++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your two threads are manipulating the same output buffer, overwriting each other. Don't share memory between threads if you can possibly avoid it; all it causes is grief.

If the point of this exercise is to learn how to manipulate raw threads then take a step back and study why sharing memory across two threads is a bad idea.

If the point of this exercise is to parallelize the computation of a fractal then forget about manipulating raw threads. You will do much better to learn how to use the **Task Parallel Library**.

Threads are logically *workers*, and who wants to manage a bunch of workers? The TPL encourages you to see parallization as the manipulation of *tasks* that can be done in parallel. Let the TPL take care of figuring out how many workers to assign to your tasks.

Comment: I'm using Tasks now and somehow I'm still getting the same error, only it isn't coming until pixels_completed++ this time...

Comment: @user1653653: Let me repeat myself: **don't share memory between threads unless you know what you're doing.** Using tasks does not make your code magically threadsafe, it just eliminates the need to manage the workers yourself. Incrementing a counter is the first thing that any tutorial in threading will tell you is **not a safe operation on multiple threads**.  Make your tasks so that **every task is entirely self-contained**, so that it touches nothing that is shared by any other task, unless you have *certainty* that the shared access is safe.

Comment: If they're not writing to the same field can they at least write to the same class?

Comment: @user1653653: Classes are not storage locations; you don't write to them.

Comment: I mean different fields within the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is initializing `this.output` multiple times (once for each thread).

Both of your threads use the same `this` and when the first thread initialized `this.output`'s columns, the second thread re-initializes it, and the first thread loses its allocated memory.

So, `this.output[x]` will not be existed in the first thread anymore (`missing an object reference` exception).

This also explains why your code runs flawlessly with just one thread.

The easy solution is to initialize the whole array at the very beginning.

Comment: I initialized the array outside of the thread method, and I get the same error...

Comment: @user1653653 what is your intention? do you want to overwrite same data by any thread without any control?

Comment: You are probably missing something else then, feel free to update your question with your new code :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems fishy.

But if you believe it is correct and resetting `this.output` data is necessary in each thread, then do the following:

1. Make temporary array
2. Change `[x][y]` to [x,y]
3. Change `[][]` to `[,]`
4. Apply `lock` before setting to `this.output`